# Doesn't want to start

Tags: starting, diesel, renault, kangoo

Some help would really be appreciated. I've got a diesel Renault kangoo 1.5 dci 2006 that is being stubborn. It will start with e-z start without too much trouble. I thought the issue was a blown fuse caused by someone attempting to connect up a leisure battery off the starter battery and just cutting off the cable. However after replacing the blown 80a fuse (which I have no idea what it runs to, could that have been damaged?) I still have the issue. 
Showed it to a friend and they noticed air bubbles in the fuel lines. I have tried using the priming bulb but have not felt much in the way of pressure but can't find a leak. Help!

Comment: When did the problem start? Was it related to the leisure battery?

Comment: This is a diesel engined vehicle?

Comment: Fit a quality new fuel filter and bleed it  - air bubbles in fuel feed or return could cause bad starting, as a diesel (1.5 dci) any air in the system is a no no.

Answer (score 1):

The Renault Kangoo DCI is renowned for air passing in the fuel lines. There are a number of places it can get in such as the fuel filter housing or any joint in the fuel lines in the engine bay.

The seem to have used a poor plastic and over time the plastic in the joints degrades and leaks. Rather than spending hours and hours finding what joint is as fault and then to have another one fail at a later date it is recommenced to replace the engine bay fuel pipes.

The pipes come as a set, there are a few after market ones available or you can buy them from Renault. They join just behind the front right wheel on the inner chassis leg which go to the filter, two more leave this to the fuel pump and rail.

So again, replace the fuel filter, fuel pipes and fuel primer bulb. Then you should not see any air bubbles in the pipes and the van should start easier.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, should have posted as an answer...
Fit a quality new fuel filter and bleed it - air bubbles in fuel feed or return could cause bad starting, as a diesel (1.5 dci) any air in the system is a no no.

Comment: I did think of replacing the fuel pump possibly?

Comment: How could I bleed the system?